# Matching a set of strings against a string to maximize the number of possible matches

Tags: algorithm, string-matching

I have a very interesting problem.

I have a set of strings and I would like to know how to best match a combination these strings in another string against a maximization function.

An example would be.  Say I have the set:

```
['aabbcaa', 'bbc']
```

and I have the string

```
'fgabbcdaabbcaaef'
```

and the possible matches for this are:

```
fga[bbc]daadaa[bbc]aaef
```

or

```
fga[bbc]daad[aabbcaa]ef
```

Now, given a simple maximization function, I would say that `fga[bbc]daad[aabbcaa]ef` is the winner due to the number of total characters matched. A different maximization function could give more weight to larger words replaced instead of total characters.

I would love to know if someone could point me to some algos on how to do this.  What I’m stumped by is after I find a set of potential matches I’m not sure how to maximize the set of words to choose in an efficient way.

The dictionary, the words of the dictionary, and the word that’s being matched against, could be of any size.

Would appreciate any help I could get with this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer and it works nicely.  Pseudocode is:

- Loop over the set and find everywhere the set strings match in the target string.  Store the start_index, end_index, and give a score to that string for matching.  I currently use the length of string.
- Then using all the matches found, run it through the "Weighted Interval Scheduling" algorithm to find the optimal set of matches
- https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse521/13wi/slides/06dp-sched.pdf